# Compiling java code on a build machine gives major.minor error 52

Tags: windows, compilation, java-8

Other developer had pushed the code and we are building it on a build machine.
I was getting Unsupported Major.minor version 52 error.

Is there any way to find the version of JDK used while developing the Java file.

Could some one please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `developing` you probably mean `compiling` the java file.

Take the `.class` file and look inside it with `javap`:

```
javap -c -verbose ConstructorReference.class
```

Output (at the beginning of the output)

```
 public class org.ConstructorReference
 minor version: 0
 major version: 53
```

> 53 - means java 9
>
> 52 - means java 8

You get the error because the build machine is using most probably jdk-7 and your class files were compiled with jdk-8 (evidence of 52).

Comment: No, not by comipling. Other developer has created a .java file on his PC and shared me the repo . I have to build this code on a build machine.
So was wondering how to get to know the JDK version used on the developers PC

Comment: @manuendla when are you getting the exception then? at which point? when you compile it? when it runs somewhere?

Comment: This is a TestNG project, I have just copied the code, running it on a build machine

Comment: @manuendla so the build machine is *compiling* the code with jdk-8, but it runs the tests with jre-7. Check the settings of those.