# How to find OC4J server jdk version?

Tags: java, server, java-6, oc4j, java-5

I'm facing problem with deploying web application into OC4j 10.1.3 server and getting error with "**java wrong version 50.0 should be 49.0**".

I know that, this is because of jdk version clashing which is being used for compiling the application and version which is used in oc4j server.

I have compiled application in jdk 1.6, any how i know that version 49 is jdk 1.5. But i want it to confirm from server console or config file.

So guide me, how to find the jdk version which is being used in oc4j server?

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file/1096159#1096159

Comment: Thanks i verified earlier as well, is there any way to check it in server console itself.

Answer (score 0):

> How to find OC4J server jdk version?

By Default bundled with version of JDK 1.5. If you want to update it with a later version with latest patched

Update the JDK for the complete Oracle Application Server installation:

Shutdown OAS.

1. Install the latest JDK in another directory according to your OS’ requirement.
2. After installation, go to OAS directory, rename $OAS_HOME/jdk to $OAS_HOME/jdk.1.5.0_05_bak
3. Copy the complete newly installed jdk directory to $OAS_HOME, you should now have new jdk version for your OAS.

To update only your existing OC4J container to use a different version of JDK:

1. Shut down your OC4J container. (eg. SOA_OC4J)
2. In opmn.xml, locate the entry for “SOA_OC4J” in the start-parameters section.
3. Add following line that points to your newly installed JDK directory (update the directory according to your env):
4. Start the OC4J container

Comment: Thanks for the details, FYI this server setup had been done years ago and we were not aware of it.Is there any way to confirm that, server is using jdk 1.5?

Comment: Java -version & Javac -version through cmd
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14011/chap1.htm