# How to get the version of the embedded java

Tags: java

I am implementing GetDown on my application and configure it to embed a `JRE` to prevent problems of version installed by the users.
But I don't find a way to check if the embedded `JRE` is really the one used, and i can uninstall java on my computer to test it (my employer didn't give me admin access, yay!).

The command `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` show me the java installed on the user's computer, but how can I get what verion of java the application is really using.

Thank you for your answers and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What ide are you using?

Comment: Do you have access to a .class file generated? If so, follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file

Comment: The system property `java.version` **does** give you the version of the JVM that you are currently *running* (not of something installed on your system but not currently running). What made you think otherwise?

Comment: A fun fact linked to wha t@Andreaジーティーオー said: if you check the hexa of a .class file, you'll see something like `ca fe ba be 00 00 00 34  `, where 34 is the java version. `cafe babe` is the mark of a java class file.

Comment: The OP is not asking for the version of Java used to compile a class, but is asking for the version of Java that is currently running.

Comment: that command does **not** show you the Java version that is "installed". It shows the version of the JRE that is used to **run** that code - you can't call `System.getProperty()` outside of a running JVM.

Comment: You have provided you own answer since you asked "_how can I get what verion of java the application is really using._" and `System.getProperty("java.version")` provide the version of the JVM executing the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));` doesn't show which Java version is installed on the user's computer, since multiple versions can be installed. It shows which Java version the program is currently being executed on.

Comment: I don't think so, I use the jre 1.8.0_111 as embedded java, and on another computer when the application call that command, it show me the version 1.8.0_60.

Comment: because that other computer use "1.8.0_60".. This is the version of the JVM running the compiled code. Which is what you asked "_how can I get what verion of java the application is really using._"

Comment: So my configuration don't work...mmmh that a possibility.

Comment: Check the JDK defined in your IDE (in the project properties in general) and if you run it in command line check the JAVA version with `java -version`. This should show the same result as `System.getProperty`

Comment: My IDE (eclipse neon 2) use JDK 1.8.0_111 installed on m'y computer (thas where I took/duplicate the jre to embed). I will try on a computer without java installed.

Answer (score 0):

the command System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version")); give effectively the version used by the application. It was a bad deduction on my part.
At the begining I used the JRE 1.8.0_111, but the command returned 1.8.0_60 without reason (I had the problem even on a computer whithout java instaled).

I have tried changing the embedded JRE (using 1.8.0_172) and now the command return  1.8.0_172 . So i assume the problem was from the previous JRE (1.8.0_111).

Thank you for all your answers, they give me tracks to follow.