# Custom Function Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 TIBCO Designer 5.7

Tags: tibco-business-works, tibco-designer

I am using TIBCO Designer 5.7.

In the Mapper pallet of my Designer code, I am using a Custom Java Function "Utilities", but while using it it is giving me an error saying "Custom Function Utilities: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0".In the XPath section it is saying "no such function". I assume this is because of incompatibility of TIBCO's Java with my Java JDK. Can someone explain in detail how to resolve this issue?

Please refer to the image for the error.

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am able to resolve it via below steps:-
1) Go to the folder where your Custom java class is stored, in my case it is "Utilities.java"
[image: custom class.java]

2) Now we will create a .class file for this class USING the TIBCO’s java, not our own local installed java jre, as the new .class file will be of TIBCO’s,
for this Go to your TIBCO_HOME>tibcojre64>1.6.0>bin, Run CMD there and give the commandad below:-
[image: command to create .class file]

This will create a Utilities.class file in the same folder

3) Now create a Custom Java function in Designer and refer this .class file.

[image: java custom function]

4) Now Load-> Apply-> save the project and Restart your designer. The error will be gone

Comment: Looks like you have two custom function activities with same class name.

Comment: here is tutorial how to create custom function http://tutorialspedia.com/tibco-java-custom-function-video-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

As you said you have incompatible Java version in your Tibco JRE and custom function .class file. 
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error comes when you run a class file created using Java 1.7 (major version 51.0) into a lower Tibco environment JRE version for example JRE 6 or 5.

The major numbers are:

```
Java SE 13 = 57,
Java SE 12 = 56,
Java SE 11 = 55,
Java SE 10 = 54,
Java SE 9 = 53,
Java SE 8 = 52,
Java SE 7 = 51,
Java SE 6.0 = 50,
Java SE 5.0 = 49,
JDK 1.4 = 48,
JDK 1.3 = 47,
JDK 1.2 = 46,
JDK 1.1 = 45
```

(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout)

You can check Tibco JRE version in Tibco Designer  **Help->Runtime Environment -> Java tab ->(java.runtime.version)**

You can check version of you custom function by

```
javap -verbose MyFunction.class| findstr "major"
```

[how to check the jdk version used to compile a .class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096148/how-to-check-the-jdk-version-used-to-compile-a-class-file)

So, you need either change your tibco JRE version to be compatible with your class version or re-build you custom function class with the version that compatible with your Tibco JRE.

You can use -target option for specifying java version in java compiler when build your function.

```
javac -target 1.6 MyFunction.java
```

If you don't have source code of the function you can use decompiler like JD http://jd.benow.ca/

For changing JRE in Tibco you need to reconfigure all .tra files to new java version path. You can use /tra//bin/traUpgradeManager utility for that:

```
traUpgradeManager -path C:/tibco/bw/5.7 -jre C:/tibco/jre/1.7
traUpgradeManager -path C:/tibco -jre C:/tibco/jre/1.7
```

Please see https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-33612 for the details.

Please note that changing JRE in all tibco environments may be not trivial process. In your case it's match easier to re-compile the custom function.

Comment: HI, How can I change my Tibco JRE version to be compatible with my class version?

Comment: Please see https://support.tibco.com/s/article/Tibco-KnowledgeArticle-Article-33612