# What version of javac built my jar?

Tags: java, jar

How can I tell what version of the Java compiler was used to build a jar?  I have a jar file, and it could have been built in any one of three JDKs.  We need to know exactly which one, so we can certify compatibility.  Is the compiler version embedded somewhere in the class files or jar?

Comment: You can tell the major verson by looking at the manifest file. You can tell the target version by looking at the class files themselves however the JDKs can produce class files for earlier versions of java using the -target option, so looking at the first bytes might not be accurate.

Comment: In MANIFEST.MF you can find something like `Created-By: 1.7.0_13 (Oracle Corporation)`

Comment: Looks like Maven 3 does this `Created-By: Apache Maven` and `Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_25`

Comment: Please check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065/tool-to-read-and-display-java-class-versions

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can't tell from the JAR file itself, necessarily.

Download a hex editor and open one of the class files inside the JAR and look at byte offsets 4 through 7.  The version information is built in.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Note: As mentioned in the comment below,

> those bytes tell you what version the class has been compiled FOR, not
>   what version compiled it.

Comment: To be pedantic, those bytes tell you what version the class has been compiled FOR, not what version compiled it. Java allows you to compile code so that they're compatible with earlier versions of Java. However, this only applies to byte code and format. It will happily compile code that references JDK 6 libraries into a JDK 5 format, for example. The JDK 5 will load the class, but can't run it as the JDK 5 library doesn't have the code referenced from JDK 6.

Comment: We could find it in the manifest file as Created-By: 1.7.0_21-b11 (Oracle Corporation)

Comment: **[The other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3313839/641451) tells how to easy check via the command line**

Answer (score 402):

A `jar` is merely a container. It is a file archive ā la [`tar`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) or [`zip`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)). While a `jar` may have interesting information contained within it's **META-INF** hierarchy, it has no obligation to specify the vintage of the classes within its contents. For that, one must examine the `class` files therein.

As as [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey) mentioned in comment to the original question, you can't necessarily know which JDK release built a given `class` file, but you can find out the byte code class version of the `class` file contained in a `jar`.

Yes, this kinda sucks, but the first step is to extract one or more classes from the `jar`. For example:

```
$ jar xf log4j-1.2.15.jar
```

On Linux, Mac OS X or Windows with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.org/) installed, the [file(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command knows the class version.

```
$ file ./org/apache/log4j/Appender.class
./org/apache/log4j/Appender.class: compiled Java class data, version 45.3
```

Or alternatively, using `javap` from the JDK as @jikes.thunderbolt aptly points out:

```
$ javap -v ./org/apache/log4j/Appender.class | grep major
 major version: 45
```

For `Windows` environments without either `file` or `grep`

```
> javap -v ./org/apache/log4j/Appender.class | findstr major
 major version: 45
```

FWIW, I will concur that `javap` will tell a whole lot more about a given `class` file than the original question asked.

Anyway, a different class version, for example:

```
$ file ~/bin/classes/P.class
/home/dave/bin/classes/P.class: compiled Java class data, version 50.0
```

The list below shows the class version major number and JDK version where that class major version was introduced.

Note: *class version does not necessarily identify the JDK used to compile the class - it only identifies the earliest version which may have produced it*.

For example, class major version 52 could have been produced by any JDK after Java 7.

- 45.3 = Java 1.1
- 46 = Java 1.2
- 47 = Java 1.3
- 48 = Java 1.4
- 49 = Java 5
- 50 = Java 6
- 51 = Java 7
- 52 = Java 8
- 53 = Java 9
- 54 = Java 10
- 55 = Java 11
- 56 = Java 12
- 57 = Java 13
- 58 = Java 14
- 59 = Java 15
- 60 = Java 16
- 61 = Java 17
- 62 = Java 18
- 63 = Java 19
- 64 = Java 20
- 65 = Java 21
- 66 = Java 22

Comment: My version of `file` didn't show that, but I was able to check the class manually with this command: `hexdump ~/bin/classes/P.class | head`. Just look at the eighth byte and convert to decimal.

Comment: FYI 'file' seems to depend on the Java version as to whether it will also display the JDK version. 

On CentOS/Oracle Linux and a Java 6 compiled class I get 

"compiled Java class data, version 50.0 (Java 1.6)" 

but when I run it on a class compiled with Java 7 I just get the generic version 

"compiled Java class data, version 51.0"

Comment: ``JAR=something.jar ; unzip -p $JAR `unzip -l $JAR | grep '\.class$' | head -1` | file -``

Comment: @JarettMillard my cygwin `file file.class` (5.22-1) didn't show java class target initially: "file.class:  [architecture=6909806] [architecture=6845039]". However `file -k file.class` did that: "file.class:  [architecture=6909806] [architecture=6845039] compiled Java class data, version 50.0 (Java 1.6)". It looks like `file` got only first match in its magicfiles db without `-k`.

Comment: Using "javap -p <class> | grep major" is not be reliable. If a pom.xml has a source/target of 1.7, javap will always give you "major version: 51" regardless whether you use JDK 1.7, JDK 1.8 or JDK 1.9 to compile.

Comment: @user2569618 that is an excellent point! I will edit answer to reflect the class file version doesn't uniquely identify JDK version - it is an inequality .. JDK N or later.

Answer (score 68):

Here is Java's way to find this information.

Windows: `javap -v <class> | findstr major`
Unix: `javap -v <class> | grep major`

For example:
`> javap -v Application | findstr major
  major version: 51`

Comment: of all the answers given, your answer is the most concise and do not involve writing 10 lines of code to know the version information. +1 for that

Comment: What is `<class>` parameter for?

Comment: @Dims The ".class" file you're trying to find the version of. In his example, he has an `Application.class` file and it turned out to be compiled for Java 7 (`major version: 51`).

Comment: These commands deliver the target JVM version, not the `javac` version that compiled the .class files, which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 22):

There is no need to unpack the JAR (if one of the class names is known or is looked up e.g. using 7zip), so on Windows the following would be sufficient:

```
javap -cp log4j-core-2.5.jar -verbose org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger | findstr major
```

Comment: This works on linux, too (except you'd use grep instead of findstr of course)

Comment: These commands deliver the target JVM version, not the `javac` version that compiled the .class files, which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 17):

Since I needed to analyze fat jars I was interested in the version of each individual class in a jar file. Therefore I took Joe Liversedge approach 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27877215/1497139 and combined it with David J. Liszewski' https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313839/1497139 class number version table to create a bash script jarv to show the versions of all class files in a jar file.

**usage**

```
usage: ./jarv jarfile
 -h|--help: show this usage
```

**Example**

```
jarv $Home/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar

java 1.4 org.apache.log4j.Appender
java 1.4 org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton
java 1.4 org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender$DiscardSummary
java 1.4 org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender$Dispatcher
...
```

**Bash script jarv**

```
#!/bin/bash
# WF 2018-07-12
# find out the class versions with in jar file
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313532/what-version-of-javac-built-my-jar

# uncomment do debug
# set -x

#ansi colors
#http://www.csc.uvic.ca/~sae/seng265/fall04/tips/s265s047-tips/bash-using-colors.html
blue='\033[0;34m'  
red='\033[0;31m'  
green='\033[0;32m' # '\e[1;32m' is too bright for white bg.
endColor='\033[0m'

#
# a colored message 
#   params:
#     1: l_color - the color of the message
#     2: l_msg - the message to display
#
color_msg() {
  local l_color="$1"
  local l_msg="$2"
  echo -e "${l_color}$l_msg${endColor}"
}

#
# error
#
#   show an error message and exit
#
#   params:
#     1: l_msg - the message to display
error() {
  local l_msg="$1"
  # use ansi red for error
  color_msg $red "Error: $l_msg" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

#
# show the usage
#
usage() {
  echo "usage: $0 jarfile"
  # -h|--help|usage|show this usage
  echo " -h|--help: show this usage"
  exit 1 
}

#
# showclassversions
#
showclassversions() {
  local l_jar="$1"
  jar -tf "$l_jar" | grep '.class' | while read classname
  do
    class=$(echo $classname | sed -e 's/\.class$//')
    class_version=$(javap -classpath "$l_jar" -verbose $class | grep 'major version' | cut -f2 -d ":" | cut -c2-)
    class_pretty=$(echo $class | sed -e 's#/#.#g')
    case $class_version in
      45.3) java_version="java 1.1";;
      46) java_version="java 1.2";;
      47) java_version="java 1.3";;
      48) java_version="java 1.4";;
      49) java_version="java5";;
      50) java_version="java6";;
      51) java_version="java7";;
      52) java_version="java8";;
      53) java_version="java9";;
      54) java_version="java10";;
      *) java_version="x${class_version}x";;
    esac
    echo $java_version $class_pretty
  done
}

# check the number of parameters
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  usage
fi

# start of script
# check arguments
while test $# -gt 0
do
  case $1 in
    # -h|--help|usage|show this usage
    -h|--help) 
      usage
      exit 1
      ;;
    *)
     showclassversions "$1"
  esac
  shift
done
```

Comment: Great script ! I was able to check java versions of jars.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the script! Just a hint from my side. `head -1` may be used in conjunction with the script: usually, it is enough to see the version of the first class in the jar file.

Answer (score 16):

The Java compiler (`javac`) does not build jars, it translates Java files into class files. The Jar tool (`jar`) creates the actual jars. If no custom manifest was specified, the default manifest will specify which version of the JDK was used to create the jar.

Comment: While being true, this doesn't provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @zb226 AFAIK the version of the compiler used to compile the classes cannot be obtained from the class files, only the version that the classes were compiled _for_. The information I gave provides the only (standard) information that is available about what version built the artefact. If that's not what is being asked, the question should be reworded.

Comment: OK, I was looking at that from a pragmatical standpoint, but I see your point now, downvote removed :)

Answer (score 13):

you can find Java compiler version from .class files using a Hex Editor.

Step 1:
Extract .class files from jar file using a zip extractor

step 2: open .class file with a hex editor.(I have used notepad++ hex editor plugin. This plugin reads file as binary and shows it in hex)
You can see below. 
[image]

Index 6 and 7 gives major version number of the class file format being used.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file

Java SE 11 = 55 (0x37 hex)

Java SE 10 = 54 (0x36 hex)

Java SE 9 = 53 (0x35 hex)

Java SE 8 = 52 (0x34 hex),

Java SE 7 = 51 (0x33 hex),

Java SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex),

Java SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex),

JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex),

JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex),

JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex),

JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex).

Answer (score 5):

One liner (Linux)

`unzip -p mylib.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

This prints the content of `MANIFEST.MF` file to stdout (hopefully there is one in your jar file :)

Depending on what built your package, you will find the JDK version in `Created-By` or `Build-Jdk` key.

Comment: Note that there is no obligation for these fields to be present in `MANIFEST.MF`, as well as there is no obligation for the values to be correct (Yes, I've once encountered a `.jar` where the value was bogus).

Comment: These commands deliver the target JVM version, not the `javac` version that compiled the .class files, which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 5):

#### IntelliJ Users

- Install the plugin Archive Browser

[image]

- Open the Jar in Intellij. You can simply add the jar to any project by dragging and dropping the jar file from the file browser.
- Browse through the jar file to locate a class file and the IntelliJ's decompiler should show the version of Java used to create the jar.

[image: IntelliJ shows java version]

Answer (score 4):

You can tell the Java binary version by [inspecting the first 8 bytes](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/07/java-finding-class-versions.html) (or using an [app](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/11/java-application-to-check-binary-class.html) that can).

The compiler itself doesn't, to the best of my knowledge, insert any identifying signature. I can't spot such a thing in the file [VM spec class format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html) anyway.

Comment: These commands deliver the target JVM version, not the `javac` version that compiled the .class files, which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 4):

The [code posted by Owen](http://www.thatsjava.com/java-essentials/30681/) can tell you the information mentioned by a number of the other answers here:

```
public void simpleExample ()
{
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream ("mytest.class");
    parseJavaClassFile ( fis );
}
protected void parseJavaClassFile ( InputStream classByteStream ) throws Exception
{
    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream ( classByteStream );
    magicNumber = dataInputStream.readInt();
    if ( magicNumber == 0xCAFEBABE )
    {
        int minorVer = dataInputStream.readUnsignedShort();
        int majorVer = dataInputStream.readUnsignedShort();
        // do something here with major & minor numbers
    }
}
```

See also [this](http://mindprod.com/products1.html#JARCHECK) and [this](http://clirr.sourceforge.net/) site. I ended up modifying the Mind Products code quickly to check what each of my dependencies was compiled for.

Comment: These commands deliver the target JVM version, not the `javac` version that compiled the .class files, which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 4):

Developers and administrators running Bash may find these convenience functions helpful:

```
jar_jdk_version() {
  [[ -n "$1" && -x "`command -v javap`" ]] && javap -classpath "$1" -verbose $(jar -tf "$1" | grep '.class' | head -n1 | sed -e 's/\.class$//') | grep 'major version' | sed -e 's/[^0-9]\{1,\}//'
}

print_jar_jdk_version() {
  local version
  version=$(jar_jdk_version "$1")
  case $version in 49) version=1.5;; 50) version=1.6;; 51) version=1.7;; 52) version=1.8;; esac
  [[ -n "$version" ]] && echo "`basename "$1"` contains classes compiled with JDK version $version."
}
```

You can paste them in for one-time usage or add them to `~/.bash_aliases` or `~/.bashrc`. The results look something like:

```
$ jar_jdk_version poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar
49
```

and

```
$ print_jar_jdk_version poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar
poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar contains classes compiled with JDK version 1.5.
```

**EDIT**
As [jackrabbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3707/jackrabbit) points out, you can't 100% rely on the manifest to tell you anything useful. If it was, then you could pull it out in your favorite UNIX shell with `unzip`:

```
$ unzip -pa poi-ooxml-3.5-FINAL.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 11.3-b02 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: yegor
Specification-Title: Apache POI
Specification-Version: 3.5-FINAL-20090928
Specification-Vendor: Apache
Implementation-Title: Apache POI
Implementation-Version: 3.5-FINAL-20090928
Implementation-Vendor: Apache
```

This .jar doesn't have anything useful in the manifest about the contained classes.

Comment: These commands deliver the target JVM version, not the `javac` version that compiled the .class files, which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this on command line using following process :

If you know any of the class name in jar, you can use following command :

```
javap -cp jarname.jar -verbose packagename.classname | findstr major
```

example :

```
    C:\pathwherejarlocated> javap -cp jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar -verbose com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException | findstr major
```

Output :

```
    major version: 51
```

Quick Reference :

```
JDK 1.0 — major version 45 
DK 1.1 — major version 45 
JDK 1.2 — major version 46 
JDK 1.3 — major version 47 
JDK 1.4 — major version 48 
JDK 1.5 — major version 49 
JDK 1.6 — major version 50 
JDK 1.7 — major version 51 
JDK 1.8 — major version 52 
JDK 1.9 — major version 53
```

> PS : if you dont know any of the classname,  you can easily do this by
>   using any of the jar decompilers or by simply using following command to extract jar file
>   :
>
> ```
> jar xf myFile.jar
> ```

Comment: Linux/mac users can replace `findstr` with `grep`:
`javap -cp jarname.jar -verbose packagename.classname | grep major`

Comment: Thank you Shubham for improving this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Each class file has a version number embedded for the byte code level which the JVM use to see if it likes that particular byte code chunk or not.  This is 48 for Java 1.4, 49 for Java 1.5 and 50 for Java 6.

Many compilers exist which can generate byte code at each level, javac uses the "-target" option to indicate which byte code level to generate, and the Java 6 javac can generate byte code for at least 1.4, 1.5 and 6.  I do not believe that the compiler inserts anything that can identify the compiler itself which is what I think you ask for.  Also the Eclipse compiler is increasingly being used, as it is a single jar which can run with the JRE only.

In a jar file there is usually many classes, and each of them is independent, so you need to investigate all classes in the jar to be certain about the characteristics of the contents.

Answer (score 2):

A good deal of times, you might be looking at whole jar files, or war files that contain many jar files in addition to themselves.

Because I didn't want to hand check each class, I wrote a java program to do that:

https://github.com/Nthalk/WhatJDK

```
./whatjdk some.war
some.war:WEB-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar contains classes compatible with Java1.1
some.war contains classes compatible with Java1.6
```

While this doesn't say what the class was compiled WITH, it determines what JDK's will be able to LOAD the classes, which is probably what you wanted to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on @David J. Liszewski's answer, I ran the following commands to extract the jar file's manifest on Ubuntu:

```
# Determine the manifest file name:
$ jar tf LuceneSearch.jar | grep -i manifest
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

# Extract the file:
$ sudo jar xf LuceneSearch.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

# Print the file's contents:
$ more META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_25-b30 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: org.wikimedia.lsearch.config.StartupManager
```

Comment: Or, as a one-liner: `unzip -p LiceneSearch.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: These commands deliver the target JVM version, not the `javac` version that compiled the .class files, which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [Jonathon Faust's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313548/1529709) and [McDowell's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3313588/1529709) answers: If you're on a *nix based system, you can use `od` (one of the earliest Unix programs<sup>1</sup> which should be available practically everywhere) to query the `.class` file on a binary level:

```
od -An -j7 -N1 -t dC SomeClassFile.class
```

This will output the familiar integer values, e.g. `50` for `Java 5`, `51` for `Java 6` and so on.

<sup>1</sup> Quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_(Unix)

Comment: These commands deliver the target JVM version, not the `javac` version that compiled the .class files, which is what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I as well wrote my own bash script to dump the Java version required by all the jars passed at the command line... Mine is a bit rough, but works for me ;-)

#### example usage

```
$ jar_dump_version_of_jvm_required.sh *.jar
JVM VERSION REQUIRED: 46.0, /private/tmp/jars/WEB-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar
JVM VERSION REQUIRED: 49.0, /private/tmp/jars/WEB-INF/lib/json-smart-1.1.1.jar
JVM VERSION REQUIRED: 50.0, /private/tmp/jars/WEB-INF/lib/jsontoken-1.0.jar
JVM VERSION REQUIRED: 50.0, /private/tmp/jars/WEB-INF/lib/jsr166y-1.7.0.jar
```

#### jar_dump_version_of_jvm_required.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$(PWD)
function show_help()
{
  ME=$(basename $0)
  IT=$(cat <<EOF

  Dumps the version of the JVM required to run the classes in a jar file

  usage: $ME JAR_FILE

  e.g. 

  $ME myFile.jar    ->  VERSION: 50.0     myFile.jar

  Java versions are:
  54 = Java 10
  53 = Java 9
  52 = Java 8
  51 = Java 7
  50 = Java 6
  49 = Java 5
  48 = Java 1.4
  47 = Java 1.3
  46 = Java 1.2
  45.3 = Java 1.1

EOF
  )
  echo "$IT"
  exit
}

if [ "$1" == "help" ]
then
  show_help
fi
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  show_help
fi

function unzipJarToTmp()
{
  JAR=$1
  CLASS_FILE=$(jar -tf "$JAR" | grep \.class$ | grep -v '\$' | head -n1 | awk '{print $NF}')
  OUT_FILE="$CLASS_FILE"
  #echo "J=$JAR C=$CLASS_FILE O=$OUT_FILE"
  jar xf "$JAR" "$CLASS_FILE"

  MAJOR=$(javap -v "$OUT_FILE" 2>&1 | grep major | awk -F' ' '{print $3'})
  MINOR=$(javap -v "$OUT_FILE" 2>&1 | grep minor | awk -F' ' '{print $3'})
  if [ -z "$MAJOR" ]
  then
    echo "JVM VERSION REQUIRED: NA as no classes in $JAR"
  else
    echo "JVM VERSION REQUIRED: $MAJOR.$MINOR, $JAR"
  fi
}

# loop over cmd line args
for JAR in "$@"
do
  cd "$DIR"
  JAR_UID=$(basename "$JAR" | sed s/.jar//g)
  TMPDIR=/tmp/jar_dump/$JAR_UID/
  mkdir -p "$TMPDIR"
  JAR_ABS_PATH=$(realpath $JAR)

  cd "$TMPDIR"

  #echo "$JAR_ABS_PATH"
  unzipJarToTmp "$JAR_ABS_PATH"
  #sleep 2
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the existing answers i tried to build something which is more convenient and should work on most OS (it depends on `cat`, `xxd` and `awk`), you just have to put your class file name of a class extracted from your jar.

```
cat YOUR_FILE.class | xxd -s 7 -l1 | awk  '{print $2}' | sed -e 's/34/Java SE 8/' -e 's/35/Java SE 9/' -e 's/36/Java SE 10/' -e 's/37/Java SE 11/' -e 's/38/Java SE 12/' -e 's/39/Java SE 13/' -e 's/3a/Java SE 14/' -e 's/3b/Java SE 15/' -e 's/3c/Java SE 16/' -e 's/3d/Java SE 17/' -e 's/3e/Java SE 18/'
```

The convenient mapping to human readable versions works for major versions beginning by Java 8. (otherwise you get the plain hex version number of the major version, see link in 1. for a definition)

What is this little script based on:

1. I use the content of the class file and use `xxd` for getting the 7th byte.
   Which is by definition used for the major version, see wikipedia:
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file
2. Then i just substitute with a list for all version values beginning of hex 34 java 8 and ending with hex 3e for java 18.

Answer (score 0):

I build a little bash script [(on github)](https://github.com/beardedN5rd/java-helper/blob/master/scripts/checkJavaVersion.sh) based on Davids suggestion using the `file` command

Answer (score 0):

You check in Manifest file of jar
example:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.6.0 (IBM Corporation)

Answer (score -1):

On Windows do the following:

1. Unzip or extract the JAR file using WinZip / Java JAR command.
2. Drag and Drop one of the class files into your Eclipse Java project.
3. Open the class file.

Now Eclipse will show the exact major and minor version.