# Java - Which version was a .jar file built too?

Tags: java, jar

Is there a way to find out the JDK version used to build a .jar file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's not possible reliably, since you don't even need a JDK to build a JAR file - it's just a ZIP file with the classes and a manifest file inside.

What you can find out is what version of [the class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html) is used. The major version number maps to majorJDK releases:

```
J2SE 6.0 = 50 (0x32 hex)
J2SE 5.0 = 49 (0x31 hex)
JDK 1.4 = 48 (0x30 hex)
JDK 1.3 = 47 (0x2F hex)
JDK 1.2 = 46 (0x2E hex)
JDK 1.1 = 45 (0x2D hex)
```

However, the java compiler has an option to use the class file format of a previous version, which is frequently used to achieve downwards compatibility. But if you find a class file version major number of 50, you know that the classes were definitely not compiled with a Java 5 or earlier JDK.

Comment: While everything you say is correct, this really tells you what compiler compiled your classes, not what jar tool jar-ed your classes.  Most of the time one would assume that they come from the same toolkit.

Comment: The answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3313839/2776843 is much better. Check that too.

Answer (score 10):

Most jars are built using the provided "jar" tool packaged with the jdk.

In SUN's JDK the provided "jar" tool will add a "Created-By" line in the embedded META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.

That line will specify the version of the JDK that created the JAR (in my case "Created-By: 1.6.0_17 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)")

Other Java vendors tend to do the same.

Comment: Does the Ant jar task use the jar tool internally? Because I think rather more JAR files are built with Ant than via the command line tool.

Answer (score 9):

You can extract the class files from the jar file and use the following command:

```
javap -verbose SomeClass | grep major
```

Should give you the version number of the class files.

Answer (score 7):

In the Jars MANIFEST.MF there may be a Build-Jdk property which should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I just jar'd up a few class files and Build-Jdk is not in the MANIFEST.MF file at all.

Comment: Mmm, you may be right. I'm looking at a jar with Created-By: Apache Maven. The docs seems to agree with you however.