# A way to download only java 1.6 compatible libraries

Tags: java, maven

How I can make maven to download only java 1.6 compatible libraries?
I have tomcat 6 and java 1.6.0_38. Or how I can find incompatible libs?

http://pastebin.com/WnwZL2RX list of dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a one-time task which you have to run over the list your have provided then I would propose a manual approach described here:

[What version of javac built my jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313532/what-version-of-javac-built-my-jar/3313839#3313839)

As for automatic check then you would have to implement your own maven plugin which will use similar approach to the one described above or drill into JAR manifest in order to get the Java version.

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question i hope to be able to check back for a more satisfying answer.

Maven is not able to perform such a task - and as faar as i know (i only checked back with a 5 minute websearch) there is no plugin available for this task.

In the end Maven supports with the dependency management by resolving dependencies of dependencies and has default approaches when it comes to versions of the same dependency (*"the closest version wins"*) - regardless of this you will be in charge when it comes to compatibility between your own source and third party source.

Especially when talking about runtime incompatibility this could be a quite hard task to find out about issues.

Comment: @ArthurKharkivskiy you are very welcome - in exchange thank you for that question (i actually never thought about some sort of checker - not to be a 100% sure but have a additional "hardening component" in the build) - lets pass time and see if someone comes up with a good solution (or a new plugin :))