# How to find the minimum JDK version of a specific version of maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency

Now I use the JDK1.5 to develop the program, so I have to guarantee the maven dependencies I want to use are compatible with the JDK 1.5 . Sometimes, latest version needs jdk higher than 1.5 but older version may fit. 
But how to find the minimum JDK version of a specific version of maven dependency?
I have tried mvnrepository.com but can not find the jdk requirement. Some project home page only show the jdk requirement of latest version.
Anyone can help me? Thank you!

Comment: are we talking about manually checking or programmatically checking for minimum JDK version?

Comment: The best solution is to check the dependencies you use via [animal-sniffer-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/) and will fail your build if you use different. 
Apart from that I would suggest to upgrade to Java 7 or 8...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the major/minor version of the class files. If the JAR was built with Maven you can check the version of the JDK used to build it in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file which is most likely the minimum version.

A way to check without downloading the JAR is to check the POM on maven central e.g.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.openhft%7Cchronicle-queue%7C4.5.15%7Cbundle

needs 1.8

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:deprecation</compilerArgument>
                <compilerArgument>-XDignore.symbol.file</compilerArgument>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Something to consider, if Oracle with all it's resources doesn't support Java 7 for free, should you?

Comment: I think that 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' is not contracted to have such an information. Even worse, not all POMs have <maven-compiler-plugin> node with <source> and <target> nodes. For example for 'org.testng:testng:7.6.1' neither of your ways of checking will work.

Comment: @zer_ik If the information isn't anywhere else, you will have to try the jar or read it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times you can do like this

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>{java.sourceversion}</source>
                <target>{java.targetversion}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only one hundred percent solution is to check minimum required JDK version for `.class` files inside `jar`. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313532/what-version-of-javac-built-my-jar).