# How to know with which Java version Jar is created?

Tags: java

I have a java jar file. How can I check with which version of java , the jar file got created which build was performed. There was a recent Java upgrade happened on my system from Java Version 1.6 to Java version 1.8 and a Jar file stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, Mac OS X or Windows with [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org/) installed, the [file(1)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file) command knows the class version.

```
$ file ./org/apache/log4j/Appender.class
./org/apache/log4j/Appender.class: compiled Java class data, version 45.3
```

And if you are relegated to a Windows environment without either file or grep

```
> javap -v ./org/apache/log4j/Appender.class | findstr major
 major version: 45
```

**Reference**: [What version of javac built my jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313532/what-version-of-javac-built-my-jar/3313839#3313839)