# Unable to target byte code to earlier versions

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Can jdk 11 generate java 7 byte code? Normally, yes, but after trying

[image]

jar files are generated but looking at the version:

```
$ javap -v org/iq80/leveldb/DB.class | grep major
  major version: 52
```

it seems that the java 8 ([What version of javac built my jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313532/what-version-of-javac-built-my-jar/3313839#3313839))  is targeted instead of 7 (which is needed for an android build).

How can I force a build for 7?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/104891.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting this within your `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`.

Maven compiler plugin (see the `configuration` block):

```xml
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Gradle (anywhere top-level within the script):

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

If for some reason you are **not** using these to build, I would *seriously* consider switching. See CrazyCoder's comment for an IntelliJ solution.