# Downgrading java version in project (IntelliJ)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, javac, javap

I am trying to downgrade the target build version of java, but somehow I can´t change it within IntelliJ, don´t understeand why.

Under `File -> Project Structure -> Projects` I changed the language level and the SDK (java 11), but somehow `javap -v` shows me the major version 62

No idea why. Don´t know if it makes difference, using Fedora 37 and IntelliJ 2022.1.1

How can I downgrade the project SDK?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check the project bytecode version in `Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Java Compiler`.

Comment: YouTube video by JetBrains: [*Helen's Take On: Project SDK, Language Level and JDKs*](https://youtu.be/W4EK_KVgfkw)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/67523751/12844632 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/12900859/12844632 . Why do you use JBR (JetBrains Runtime) for running the project? I'd recommend you switch to another vendor if you're not developing IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov thank you for the hint. Somehow changing settings inside the IntelliJ does not affect anything. No idea why. Setting the source and target compbatibility in gradle fixed it first. Thank you