# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tool to read and display Java .class versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27065/tool-to-read-and-display-java-class-versions)

I am getting this error, I suspect, because I am running a program on a Java 5 VM whereas one of my dependent classes was built with Java 6.

My question: How to do I easily go through the list of all of the jar and class files in my applications to determine the version number of each class?

There has got to be a utility for doing this.

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Will the "-verbose" flag not tell you enough?

Answer (score 4):

http://code.google.com/p/versioncheck/ might be of your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use javap utility that can be found in bin directory under JDK installation.

`javap -verbose MyTest | find "major version"` if you are on Windows
`javap -verbose MyTest | grep "major version"` if you are on Unix